# Visual Studio Hanging when compiling with large header file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a large header file with a huge array in it
The header file is roughly 200mb.

When I include it in my project the project hangs when compiling.

I am using Visual studio 2010
Compiling in x64

Is there a setting I am missing?

Comment: The the arrays are large but I did set them to static and const

Comment: Adding static data via a header isn't the best solution, store the data in a resource section or a separate data file.

Comment: I agree .. I am trying to convert this massive array to a zipped binary file .. but first just want to read it in and write the file .. that is where the problem is! :)